# Oracle: Java Stored Procedures and processes

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

We need to run a Java program from within an Oracle database, so we are considering using a [Java Stored Procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/chfive.htm#BABGEJDI). The question is what happens in terms of scalability since we are going to have many concurrent executions.

(1) Will it create a new "java" process for each call made to the procedure, meaning it will startup a new JVM instance? Or (2) Will Oracle DB manage the code and use a shared JVM for running the program?

I believe and hope the option 2 is likely to be the correct one, but I was not able to find any document that can answer this question so we can proceed safely.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge it uses a shared VM. I am also looking for the specification to back my statement

Comment: Its worth going through this https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDEV/chnine.htm#JJDEV13324

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some google I found out that in fact Java Stored Procedures are optimized and interoperable, executing in the same Oracle JVM that ships with the database.

Code is integrated using the [Just-in-Time Compiler (JIT)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDEV/chnine.htm#JJDEV09000), since 11.1. Detailed information about non-functional requirements can be found in the [Developing Java Stored Procedures](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/chfive.htm#BABJHHAA) guide.

> Unlike a wrapper, which adds another layer of execution, a call
>   specification publishes the existence of a Java method. As a result,
>   when you call the method through its call specification, the run-time
>   system dispatches the call with minimal overhead.

And the [FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/faq-jvm-java-stored-procedures-097205.html#_What_is_a):

> Java Stored procedures are executed by the database JVM in database
>   memory space.